# Merge two DOMNodeLists in xpath

Tags: php, xpath

I have two DOMNodeLists

```
$textNodes = $xpath->query('//text()');
```

and

```
$titleNodes = $xpath->query('//@title');
```

**How can I merge those to DOMNodeLists so I can use it with a `foreach` loop?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

XPath supports the `|` operator for combining two node sets:

```
$textNodes = $xpath->query('//text() | //@title');
```

Imagine this simple example :

```
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0"?>
<person>
  <name>joe</name>
  <age>99</age>
</person>';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXml($xml);
$selector = new DOMXPath($doc);

$nodes = $selector->query('//name | //age');

foreach($nodes as $node) {
    echo $node->nodeName, PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: ok, that works. with the textNodes I can replace their values through `$textNode->parentNode->replaceChild($newNode, $textNode);` How can I do that for the `DomAttr` value?

Comment: Ok fine. You should consider to ask a separate question on this or adding some xml snippets to your post to answer the second question

Comment: yep, you're right. I solved it with `getAttribute` and `setAttribute`

Comment: The XPATH operator "|" combines two node-sets and thus it's different from the logical "or" operator.

Comment: @DenisGiffeler Thanks for the hint!